# SIM900/Arduino UNO R3 serial communication not working

Tags: arduino-uno

For some reason I cannot establish serial connection between the two devices. The shield is connected to the network because my number can be called, but I cannot send it any commands via the serial.
I tried several ways to wire it up:
shield rx&tx (the ones that require female jumper) to 7 & 8 of arduino, declaring 7 & 8 in the serial.
shield pins 7 & 8 (they have (serial) as label) to 7 & 8 of arduino, declarting 7 & 8 in the serial.
shield rx&tx the little holes to 7 & 8 of arduino, declaring 7 & 8 in the serial.
Tried even different pins other than 7 & 8. None worked.
I'm powering the shield with 12v transformator that can provide up to 3Ah and the arduino is connected to laptop.
Any suggestions ?
Here's the code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM900
SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); //SIM900 Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #7 & #8

void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM900
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing..."); 
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Handshaking with SIM900
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // Configuring TEXT mode
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+ZZxxxxxxxxxx\"");//change ZZ with country code and xxxxxxxxxxx with phone number to sms
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.print("Last Minute Engineers | lastminuteengineers.com"); //text content
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.write(26);
}

void loop()
{
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
```

And also, why are there so many RX/TX on the shield ? I see RXD/TXD and RX/TX.

Comment: What shield? A link to the product please.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/SODIAL-Quad-Band-Modules-Development-Arduino/dp/B077953H5P there you go friend

Answer (score 1):

To make everything work fine with this exact code and wiring from the *[lastminuteengineers](https://lastminuteengineers.com/sim900-gsm-shield-arduino-tutorial/)*, you need to change the jumper (black plastic piece) position in J11. it has to connect the pins **D8(RX)** and **D7(TX)**, which are the pins at the top of the **yellow plate**, to the two pins in the middle of the **yellow plate**.

Answer (score 0):

> And also, why are there so many RX/TX on the shield ? I see RXD/TXD and RX/TX.

There aren't.  There is only one of each. They just have them in multiple convenient places.

J11 selects the pins to use on the shield. Make sure that is set to D7 and D8. You then use pins D7 and D8 on the shield. Normally that would be mounted directly onto an Arduino and you would just use those pins in your code.

However, if you want to attach it to something that doesn't have an Arduino UNO footprint you can solder wires to the TX/RX pins in the J10/J17 "UART" header. That ignores the J11 jumpers, which only pertain to using the Arduino UNO shield headers.

As to why you can't communicate, my guess is:

- You have 9600 baud in your code:

---

```
mySerial.begin(9600);
```

However, on the Amazon product you linked to:

> The factory default setting for the GPRS Shield UART is 19200 bps 8-N-1. (Can be changed using AT commands).

Using 19200 instead of 9600 should improve matters somewhat.

Comment: It doesn't improve anything. I've tried ALL the rates. If there was a mismatch, I'd at least see some squares or other strange shapes, but I don't see anything on the serial at all!

Comment: Does your shield have jumpers on J11? The picture shows them missing.

Comment: Compare it to the one shown in this tutorial: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/sim900-gsm-gprs-shield-arduino/

Comment: I pulled out all the wires so I   could take a picture.
https://imgur.com/a/jhpzyI7
That's how j11 and j12 look. I've tried plugging females to the pointy ones. The tutorial above has some jumper caps that I have no idea what they are.

edit: I took a closer look and itseems mine are not in the same position, but I never thought these could be plugged out and replugged in, lol. That's the first thing I am going to try after work. Could you explain about those ?

Comment: Looks like its set right. Just plug it direct into your arduino. No need for wires.

Comment: The middle pair of pins are  tx and rx. the outer pairs of pins connect to the headers. The jumpers just link the two.

Comment: No, mine is not the same as the toturial. I just made them just like in the tutorial, copied the code and STILL AT wont respond!
I've also tried stacking them together.

Comment: I still haven't resolved my issue. Any other help would be greatly appreciated!
I'm also up for a video talk if this is what it takes. I absolutely want to run this.